# Excel sheet reference formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a file with months names as sheet names like,
January, february, march and so on.
And one sheet named "overview".
In total 13 sheets.

If in a cell of "overview" sheet it is written january then it will get data from "january" sheet like ='january'!A2. If the cell contains february then it will get data from "february" sheet like ='february'!A2.

Means cell in overview sheet have any month name and I want to get data from respective sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the indirect formula to convert a string to a reference. So, if cell A1 has the value say `January` which is also a name of the worksheet then you may enter a formula like `=INDIRECT(A1 & "!A2")` to pull value of cell A2 from January sheet. If the value in range A1 changes to February, the value will now be pulled from February sheet.